ASP.NET AddAuthorization with additional claims - resolving options from service provider
Using ASP.NET (AspNetCore 8, net8.0), I want to add additional claims for authorization. Our current code looks like this at the moment:
var config = configuration.GetSection("Auth").Get<AuthConfiguration>() ?? throw new ArgumentException();

services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
    .AddPolicy(AuthorizeInternalAttribute.PolicyName, policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireClaim(
                config.Claim,
                config.Accounts);
        });

This works just fine, except I'm accessing configuration at startup during configuration phase. I would like to resolve IOptions<AuthConfiguration> from within authorization handler / claim requirement, so that I can run validation of configuration at startup:
services.AddOptions<AuthConfiguration>()
    .BindConfiguration("Auth")
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();

It looks like there was possibility of using service provider, but this API is gone, I can't even find breaking change note. Other StackOverflow question/answer: Dependency Injection on Authorization Policy

I was thinking of introducing my implementation of ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement accessing options, but then I still have to instantiate it manually when configuring policy - that doesn't solve anything.
policy.AddRequirements(new MyAuthRequirement(/* still need to pass options here */));

Other option would be to add own implementation of AuthorizationHandler<> using empty "flag" requirement, e.g. MyAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyAuthRequirement> { ... }.
public class MyAuthRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class MyAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyAuthRequirement>
{
    private readonly AuthConfiguration _config;

    public MyAuthHandler(IOptions<AuthConfiguration> auth0Config)
    {
        _config = auth0Config.Value;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        MyAuthRequirement requirement)
    {
        // ... check claims, set context succeeds or not
    }
}

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthHandler>();

... but that feels like stretch to just pass two additional values (adding complexity, making intent less readable/understandable). Is there

API where I still could resolve IOptions<AuthConfiguration> while setting up authorization
another simple API so that I don't need to introduce two other things to just pass two (2!) values?


If you require such feature as dependency injection (IOptions<>), it is required to create appropriate "DI enabled" service. So I think this is the way (I would implement it like this).
